# Duplicata deletada por motivos de moderação

Tags: suporte, pergunta-específica, perguntas-duplicadas, perguntas-apagadas

Esta pergunta, [Página inicial do WordPress com estrutura diferenciada [duplicada]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50966/201), está marcada como duplicata desta outra que foi deletada: [Converter SlideShow HTML para Wordpress](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50967/converter-slideshow-html-para-wordpress).

Tinha alguma resposta lá? Será que pode ser transferida para a que está fechada e reabrir essa?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A pergunta está marcada como duplicada porque é o mesmo utilizador que perguntou duas vezes a mesma coisa.

Não vejo nenhuma resposta na pergunta apagada. Assim reabri a que estava marcada como duplicada.

Obrigado por teres reparado nessa pergunta.